# Setting React State from API call? Async loop of hell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, async-await, fetch-api

I cannot figure out what is going on. I feel like I'm running into a race condition, but I don't see it. Can anyone lay eyes on this? I'm trying to load a list of "accounts" from an API in useEffect, and use `setAccounts()` after it is complete. The API response looks fine in the network tab, but when I try to render from the state variable `accounts` I get nada.

Only going to post relevant bits (idToken is from Auth0):

```
    const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState();
    const fetchAccounts = async () => {
        const url = "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/v1/account/";
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "get",
            headers: new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer " + idToken,
            }),
        }).then((response) => response.json());
        console.log("debug", response);
        setAccounts(response);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const getToken = async () => {
            if (idToken == null) {
                const id_token = await getIdTokenClaims();
                setIdToken(id_token.__raw);
            }
        };
        getToken();
        if (idToken) {
            console.log("ID token check", idToken);
            fetchAccounts();
            getClientPortfolios();
        }
        console.log("accounts", accounts); //this prints nothing
    }, [idToken]);

    return (
        <div>
            {accounts.map((account) => {
                <div key={account.id}>{account.name}</div>;
            })}
        </div>
    )
```

At the moment, all signs point to the state variable not getting set. And the map function throws an error now: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')` 
Is there something weird about how I'm trying to do this?
For reference, here is the debug statement in fetchAccounts: [image: For reference, here is the debug statement in fetchAccounts]

Comment: `accounts` is undefined; try giving it a default value: `const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);`

Comment: `fetchAccounts` is an async operation, so when you access `accounts`, `fetchAccounts` is not completed.

Comment: @Eldar, I *think* that I understand that on a base level... but what is the right way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the initial state. Always add initial state while using state variables

```
const [accounts,setAccounts] = useState([])
```

When you use the State variable before useEffect your return will get rendered. so you will get undefined, and You haven't checked whether the accounts state has a length > 0 to do a map.

```
{
   accounts.length > 0 && accounts.map((account) => {
        return <div key={account.id}>{account.name}</div>;
   })
}
```

Comment: This results in no errors, but still isn't rendering the accounts that I know are in there from the response...

Comment: `await fetch(url, {
            //other code
        }).then((response) => return response.json())       
    };
 useEffect(() => {
        // other code
        if (idToken) {
            fetchAccounts().then(res=>{
              setAccounts(res)
 })`
can you check this one. Update your state variable in UseEffect.

Answer (score 0):

1. `const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState();` -> initialize `accounts` with value `undefined`.
2. `useEffect` -> runs *after the first render*, so you will only get a call to `setAccounts` after the first render.
3. Render uses `accounts`.

(1) + (2) + (3) mean the code `accounts.map(...)` runs before your `setAccounts` call.

Solution: check if `accounts` is defined before using it.

Comment: This makes some sense. But even if I add in a check, it's still rendering nothing (even though I know there are accounts in that variable)

Comment: @LaurenBoland That is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

your accounts state is initially undefined. After api call you are setting array of accounts.

you can use empty array as initial value.

```js
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);
```

OR you can use optional chaining

```jsx
<div>
 {accounts?.map((account) => {
                <div key={account.id}>{account.name}</div>;
            })}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh my goodness. The whole problem was my map function. I had curly braces in there, but no return call. Nothing wrong in my API calls (other than maybe the default state variable should be an empty array)

It needs to be either:

```
   return (
      <div>
          {accounts.map((account) => {
              return <div key={account.id}>{account.name}</div>;
          })}
      </div>
  )
```

or

```
   return (
      <div>
          {accounts.map((account) => (<div key={account.id}>{account.name}</div>))}
      </div>
  )
```